# Where did the single use code login option on live.com go?

Tags: office-365, outlook.com

The link to sign in with a single use code for a particular account isn't visible on the latest (as of December 2016) version of https://login.live.com/.

Where is the option to log in with a single use code on https://login.live.com/?